# time calculation issue with format php

Tags: php, time

I'm having trouble calculating the number of hours worked. 
We start with a time which starts as a string in this case ($time).
Then we change the time to 00:00:00 and store the result as a new variable ($newtime).
Then we need to calculate the difference between $time and $newtime but there is a formatting issue which I do not fully understand. Would anyone help?

```
$time = "2017-09-01 11:00:00"; //must start as a string like this
$newtime = new DateTime($time);
$newtime->setTime(00, 00,00); //change time to 00:00:00
$worktime = round((strtotime($time) - $newtime)/3600, 2);
echo "Hours Worked: " . $worktime . "<br>";
```

Comment: Why set the time to `00:00:00`?

Comment: type 8 -- Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int, that is what you mean?

Comment: yes, exactly that error 'type 8'

Comment: didn't want to over complicate things 'dekel' but that's what I need to do. calculate the difference between 00:00:00 and that time record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subtracting a timestamp with a `DateTime` object, so it tries to convert the `DateTime` object to an `int`, which it can't. You need to get the timestamp for the DateTime object, to subtract two ints:

```
<?php
$time = "2017-09-01 11:00:00"; //must start as a string like this
$newtime = new DateTime($time);
$newtime->setTime(00, 00,00); //change time to 00:00:00
$worktime = round((strtotime($time) - $newtime->getTimestamp())/3600, 2); // notice the $newtime->getTimestamp() call
echo "Hours Worked: " . $worktime . "<br>";
```

- [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Migtd)
- [DateTime::getTimestamp() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for that help 'ishegg'! Works perfectly, I love it.

Comment: I'm happy to help! If your question is resolved, please accept the answer that helped you the most to mark it as so.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing types (trying to cast object to int)... And maybe you didn't realize about the error you are making because you have disabled errors.

Please use, the method that Datetime class brings to you:

http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.gettimestamp.php

You can do it in both ways:

`$newtime->getTimestamp()`

or by using this:

`date_timestamp_get($newtime)`

As this:

```
$time = "2017-09-01 11:00:00"; //must start as a string like this
$newtime = new DateTime($time);
$newtime->setTime(00, 00,00); //change time to 00:00:00
$worktime = round((strtotime($time) - date_timestamp_get($newtime))/3600, 2);
echo "Hours Worked: " . $worktime . "<br>";
```

Please, be free of using this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f78c993f709a67ac2770d78bb809e68e3a679707